# elasticsearch river plugin is not creating geo_point type while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using elasticsearch river plugin version 1.3.0.4, which is the latest as of this post, against elasticsearch version 1.3.2.
I am trying to create a mapping with a geo_point type, but I keep failing to do so...
Here is my mapping:

```
PUT /_river/tehotels/_meta
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blah",
    "user": "",
    "password": "",
    "sql": "select id,hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_url,hotel_address,overview,city_id,star_rating,latitude as \"location.lat\",longitude as \"location.lon\" from agoda_hotels",
    "strategy": "simple",
    "autocommit": true,
    "fetchsize": 10,
    "max_rows": 0,
    "max_retries": 3,
    "max_retries_wait": "30s",
    "maxbulkactions": 1000,
    "maxconcurrentbulkactions": 8,
    "index": "teindex8",
    "type": "hotels",
    "type_mapping": {
      "hotels": {
        "properties": {
          "_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hotel_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hotel_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "hotel_url": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
          },
          "hotel_address": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
          },
          "overview": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
          },
          "city_id": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "no"
          },
          "star_rating": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the `_mapping` command, it shows as:

```
{
  "teindex8": {
    "mappings": {
      "hotels": {
        "properties": {
          "city_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hotel_address": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "hotel_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hotel_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "hotel_url": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "location": {
            "properties": {
              "lat": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "lon": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "overview": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "star_rating": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the "location" is NOT of type geo_point, but list of properties. As suspected, when I issue a query to search for location, I got the error:

```
POST /teindex8/hotels/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "20 km",
          "location": "13.441111, 103.858611"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
QueryParsingException[[teindex8] failed to find geo_point field [location]];
```

Does someone know how to fix the issue? I seem to have followed the documentation exactly...

Comment: It could be related to the ElasticSearch version being 1.3.2 (plugin version 1.3.0.4 is related to the v1.3.1). Have you tried to setup quickly a 1.3.1 ES cluster and test the same requests?

Comment: Replied below. Problem fixed so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to the version of elasticsearch. The jdbc-river plugin is still not compatible with elasticsearch 1.3.2.

[image]

When you upgrade your elasticsearch, you always need to make sure of the compatibility of its plugins. Some of them may not be supported.

For the jdbc-river plugin, you always have to check jprante plugin [repo](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc).

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by creating the mapping before running the PUT command for the jdbc load. Works great so far! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @dickyj can you valid my answer please if it helped you! :) Thanks in advance